# Threads and function call safety for global variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, global-variables

I have many threads and a global object variable. Threads use this global variable to call many functions inside of that object. I have no shared data. Are function calls thread safe?
e.g.

```
ObjectClass
{
    public:
    funA() {}
    funB() {}
    funC() {}
};

ObjectClass *obj=new ObjectClass;
```

Threads randomly call:

```
obj->funA();
obj->funB();
obj->funC();
```

Comment: You're sure that there are no data members inside `ObjectClass`? So in fact `funA` could be static, and you wouldn't even need `obj`? Because if `funA` is static, you'd just call it as `ObjectClass::funA`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is safe.  Since there is no shared state there is no possible way to get a data race.  The only caveat is if one of your threads deletes the object while the others are still trying to call functions on it then you will have undefined behavior.

If your class is truly stateless then you should consider making all these functions `static` so they don't even share a global object or just put the functions in a namespace if you want them to be scoped to a name.

Comment: Actually, it's not pure stateless, there is a init thread which initializes the variable(const) when the object is created. The later worker thread comes and starts working. So the data is not changed. Besides its inherited with overloaded functions to be used, so funA funB etc are inherited virtually.

Comment: @JaideepKarande As long as you aren't changing state you are okay.  It is valid to have multiple threads read from that same state without any synchronization.